# How to find out if a word is preceded by or followed by some specific words

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I have a requirement to check a `statement`, and if it contains a specific `ambguity word`, then do some operation.

So, here's the code:

```
for (NlpAmbiguityWords nlpAmbiguityWord : nlpAmbiguityWordsList) {
 String ambiguityWord = nlpAmbiguityWord.getWord();
 if (statement.contains(ambiguityWord)) {
    findAmbiguityWords(statement, ambiguityWord, ambiguityPhrase);
 }
}
```

Now, there is a slight change in POJO now, in addition to passing the `ambguity word`, we have to pass two more parameters, `precededBy` and `followedBy`..and both of these can contain array of strings (so they can have comma separated values). The requirement is: Ambiguity words with precededby and followedby should not be considered as ambiguity word to display in the table.

For eg: If ambiguous word is user, and preceededBy words are admin, tester, superadmin (set of 3 comma seperated values), and if the condition is true in either of 3 cases , its unambiguous.. means condition inside if should not evaluate in this case. Same logic goes for followedBy, and combination of precededBy and followedBy also.

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand you want to implement but if you want to apply some logic for every combination of precedent (from a list of comma separated words), followed (from a list of comma separated words) and ambiguityWord you can use following structure:

```
for (NlpAmbiguityWords nlpAmbiguityWord : nlpAmbiguityWordsList) {
    String ambiguityWord = nlpAmbiguityWord.getWord();
    String[] precededBys = new String[]{};
    if (nlpAmbiguityWord.getPrecededBy()!=null)
        precededBys =nlpAmbiguityWord.getPrecededBy().split(",");
    String[] followedBys = new String[]{};
    if (nlpAmbiguityWord.getFollowedBy()!=null)
        followedBys =nlpAmbiguityWord.getFollowedBy().split(",");
    for (String precedent:precededBys) {
        // TODO: apply your logic with just precedent and ambiguityWord
        for (String followed:folowedBys) {
            // TODO: apply your logic using precendent, ambiguityWord and followed
        }
    }
    for (String followed:folowedBys) {
        // TODO: apply your logic using just ambiguityWord and followed
    }
    if (statement.contains(ambiguityWord)) {
        findAmbiguityWords(statement, ambiguityWord, ambiguityPhrase);
    }
}
```